# Header in the top

Tags: php

At that time I need two view pages in one page. So that in the session i do something like this:

```
       <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){          
        ?> 

        ///My HTML CODE///
        <? 
            }
            else {
        ?>

         //Diffetent View HeRe//
        <? 
            }
            require_once('../libraries/config/configPDO.php');
        ?>
```

But now I just need to make it become one page and redirect it if they not logged in.

```
       <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){          
        ?> 

        ///My HTML CODE///
        <? 
            }
            else {header("Location: login.php");
        ?>

        <? 
            }
            require_once('../libraries/config/configPDO.php');
        ?>
```

But as you see, I put the header redirect at the bottom of the page.

How to make it simple, so that I set header location in the top of the page.

Comment: Change the condition to check whether they are not logged in and redirect if true, otherwise load the page.

Comment: `isset && !empty` is redundant nonsense. Use just `!empty` for the same effect.

Comment: Hi klaudia, you just reverse your logic first check for not session set if true redirect to login else your html code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){ 
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
} else {
    //HTML
}
```

Comment: THis is what I want. But I don't want the close `}` at the bottom.

Comment: then just remove the else part.. If not logged in it will redirect.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
       <?php
     ob_start();
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){          
    ?> 

    ///My HTML CODE///
    <? 
        require_once('../libraries/config/configPDO.php'); 
        }
        else {
               header("Location: login.php");
             }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

reverse the if to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_id']) || empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){
```

and swap the cases

Comment: As the questioner has no idea what they are doing a little more description of what goes where after the IF would have been more helpful.